# Denmark with Schengen visa type C single entry for 21 days

Tags: schengen-visas, denmark

I'm travelling to Denmark with a Schengen visa type C single entry for 21 days.

Can I travel to Paris or Switzerland and back to Denmark with the same visa?

Comment: Don't shout (writing in all caps)!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you have said so in your visa application, or if it is a "minor" adjustment of your travel plans.

Your Schengen visa allows you to enter the Schengen area once and stay for 21 days (if your 21 days are the *duration* and not the *validity period*, read up on the difference). Within the Schengen area, you can cross internal borders as many times as you like.

**But** you should not give the impression that you lied in your application.

- For example, if you wrote that you want to go do Denmark and show up in Paris, people may wonder.
- If you wrote that you will go to Germany and Italy, then going through either Switzerland or Austria on the way is your choice and does not have to be written down in advance.